# Arrays and multiple methods

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a c# program with a `main()` method holds an array of 8 integers and the second method asks the user for numbers that fill the array.

I'm lost on how to get the second method to pass the integers into the array in the main method.

Comment: What is your current code and what have you tried ?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell. What is the way used to catch the inputs ?

Answer (score 2):

My hunch is that you don't know how to work with [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [return values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/0fwzzxz2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).(How methods communicate together).If it's the case, you should really read about it.I'm going to imply you are using a console application. Look at this :

```
private void SomeMethod()
{     
  int[] myArray = new int[8];      

  for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Lenght - 1; i++)
     myArray[i] = GetInputNumber();
}

private int GetInputNumber()
{
  return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: thanks... stupid mistake.. I was going to make it fill the whole array then return it but I changed my mind in the process :P

Comment: Actually this helps, I did read about parameters and return values but my teacher doesn't explain things very well. She mostly makes us copy code she's already done but never fully explains what each item is doing or how it helps the code flow. With what you have shown me I think I can get my program going in the right direction. Thanks alot!! ^.^

Comment: No problem glad i could help. also you should never copy code you dont understand. :)